# mulit touch not working

Tags: multi-touch

hello I have this problem in ubuntu 22.04 which is touch pad gestures stopped working after some doing some customizing to ubuntu , i don't know where is the problem , so i  followed a youtube tutorial to reinstall it and when i run this command  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:touchegg/stablen , it shows this error Repository: 'deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/touchegg/stable/ubuntu/ jammy main'
Description:
Latest stable version of Touchégg for all Ubuntu flavours.

### Touchégg is an app that runs in the background and transform the gestures you make on your touchpad or touchscreen into visible actions in your desktop. Learn more at https://github.com/JoseExposito/touchegg
More info: [https://launchpad.net/~touchegg/+archive/ubuntu/stable](https://launchpad.net/%7Etouchegg/+archive/ubuntu/stable)
Adding repository.
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel.
Found existing deb entry in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/touchegg-ubuntu-stable-jammy.list
Adding deb entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/touchegg-ubuntu-stable-jammy.list
Found existing deb-src entry in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/touchegg-ubuntu-stable-jammy.list
Adding disabled deb-src entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/touchegg-ubuntu-stable-jammy.list
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 364, in 
sys.exit(0 if addaptrepo.main() else 1)
File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 357, in main
shortcut.add()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/shortcuthandler.py", line 222, in add
self.add_key()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/shortcuthandler.py", line 398, in add_key
if not all((self.trustedparts_file, self.trustedparts_content)):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 141, in trustedparts_content
key = self.lpppa.getSigningKeyData()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/resource.py", line 592, in **call**
response, content = self.root._browser._request(
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 429, in _request
raise error
lazr.restfulclient.errors.ServerError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
Response headers:

### connection: close
content-length: 30
content-type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
date: Tue, 27 Jun 2023 14:31:22 GMT
server: gunicorn
status: 500
x-lazr-oopsid: OOPS-2a7fe66d8e50b314a8338bc3b8eaae14
x-powered-by: Zope ([www.zope.org](http://www.zope.org)), Python ([www.python.org](http://www.python.org))
x-request-id: 1d64ea56-dcff-4444-bf4b-857f323bdf1d
x-vcs-revision: d6e3bf1b1b4849a91befd7dad9268049d9a506ae

### Response body:

### b'GPGKeyTemporarilyNotFoundError'

hope you can help me